# How to show a Button below a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using LinearLayout because it's the only way I can use layout_weight and I'm not familiar enough with aligning textviews evenly in RelativeLayout. (I'm new to android).
How do I get the Button below LinearLayout? Please note I've searched this question on stackoverflow but I haven't found anything that made sense to me or worked.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/llRegister2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvRegister2ShopTiming"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etRegister2StartTime"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Start Time"
                    android:textColorHint="#311D3F"
                    android:textColor="#311D3F"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etRegister2EndTime"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="End Time"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#311D3F"
                    android:textColor="#311D3F"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister2Next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="NEXT"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your layout..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/llRegister2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etRegister2StartTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Start Time"
            android:textColorHint="#311D3F"
            android:textColor="#311D3F"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:editable="false"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etRegister2EndTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="End Time"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="#311D3F"
            android:textColor="#311D3F"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:editable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegister2Next"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llRegister2"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout have property for align your views anywhere in XML. Your root view is RelativeLayout so add this line to your button :

```
android:layout_below="@+id/llRegister2" //i'd of your LinearLayout.
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Try it this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/llRegister2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnRegister2Next"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etRegister2StartTime"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Start Time"
                android:textColorHint="#311D3F"
                android:textColor="#311D3F"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etRegister2EndTime"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="End Time"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColorHint="#311D3F"
                android:textColor="#311D3F"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister2Next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="223dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Feel free to ask any doubts.